# How to SELECT rows against a Number based RANGE filter on a varchar column?

Tags: t-sql, casting, where-clause

If I have a varchar column which has the length 30:

[SpecificCode] --> **varchar(30)**  in a db table called [Item]

And if I have to query this table rows to obtain all the rows which have

SpecificCode **between 789 and 15000**

What may be the fastest way to SELECT in TSQL? (Range test is needed on a varchar field with length 30)

```
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE Item.SepecificCode --how to filter between 789 and 15000?
```

Comment: what other data is in the column? If only numbers, why?

Comment: I did not want to mention them as I believe it is not very necessery in my case.

Comment: it's necessary to give you a correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the column is full of non-numeric rubbish but no decimals

```
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE
    RIGHT('00' + Item.SpecificCode, 5) BETWEEN '789' and '15000'
    AND
    ISNUMERIC(Item.SpecificCode) = 1;
```

If just integers

```
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE
    CAST(Item.SpecificCode AS int) BETWEEN 789 and 15000;
```

If floats too:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE
    CAST(Item.SpecificCode AS float) BETWEEN 789 and 15000
    AND
    FLOOR(CAST(Item.SpecificCode AS float)) = CAST(Item.SpecificCode AS int)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE cast(Item.SepecificCode as integer) >= 789 and cast(Item.SepecificCode as interger) <= 15000
```

but to improve performance you should create a `index` in the SepecificCode column.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing sql to read the column as a INT

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Item.SepecificCode+0 between 789 and 15000;
```

AFAIK any index you have on that column is usless, beacause they are created for varchar data not integers, try see that with:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Item.SepecificCode+0 between 789 and 15000;
```